# how to save data in next activity

Tags: android

hi to all
   I what to know how to save data in next activity

Comment: do you want a short answer or a long one?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Intent` to pass data from one `Activity` to another `Activity`.
But these Intents may carry native data types like `String, int, float, double` etc.
If you want your own `Object` to be passed, you would have to implement `Serializable` interface.
An odd way is to use a static Object in a class which is globally accessible.

Answer (score 0):

you should explain clearly about your requirement. As i have understood, i think you want to access data which belongs to one activity in the other activity.

Refer the link below, you will get a clear idea.

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3

Comment: i saw in that link but i did not get the answer

Answer (score 0):

u can use intents, bundles, or any other static variables to holds data from one activity to another